# Git + gerrit для windows. Установка и настройка

Tags: windows, настройка, git

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить git и gerrit под Windows. Раньше никогда не работал с системами контроля версий. Читал туториалы, но это не помогло. В качестве IDE используется Qt Creator. Прошу подробно описать процесс установки и настройки, как на удаленном репозитории, так и на локальном (для доступа другим к моему репозиторию).
Большое спасибо.

Comment: Если туториалы не помогли, почему вы думаете, что подробное описание процесса установаки и настройки поможет?

Comment: У меня с английским не очень хорошо, поэтому установку gerrit я понять не смог. На данный момент мне удалось настроить локальный репозиторий git и соединиться с Bitbucket. Но как установить gerrit я не могу понять до сих пор.

Comment: А gerrit вообще зачем? На bitbucket уже есть code review.

Comment: Не знал, что там есть свой code review. Можно поподробней?

Comment: [Документация](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CRUCIBLE/Using+Crucible)